# ListView / DataGridView move columns to the left

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, datagridview

Using either the `ListView` or `DataGridView` i would like to move the column headers to the left side of the control.  Basically, swap the position of the Columns with the Rows.  I'm building an informational applet that will have dozens of column names with single values.

In this example i just created rows with the first column being the header.[image: Picture]

Comment: do you mean to pivot the grid?  Current rows become columns and current columns become rows?  Do you want this to be the permanent behavior of this grid or are you trying to make it dynamic?

Comment: @cdkMoose I think pivot would be an appropriate term to describe what I'm trying to do, so yes. Yes i would like this to be a permanent behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pivot your data you can achieve it in two way, it depends on what you want to modify.

If the data are on a database, you can use a Pivot query built on the fly based on how many columns you need to show as rows. The query can be done in SQL Server both using the PIVOT or the CASE statement.

If building the Query on the fly results as too complicated, you can get the table as is and build a Class with your columns as properties and create a collection reading the rows of your table and creating an object for each column you have to pivot.

If you decide to do so, Remember to Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged in the class and use a BindingList instead of a List for the classes if you want to change the data in the form from code and see the modification in your grid.

Comment: The data won't be coming from a db. If I were to do your second suggestion that would just be shifting the data around like in my example right? If so, I would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

This is tough because the datagridview really doesn't provide any help for this at all.  But the model can be very handy when you want to display a small number of objects with a large number of properties.

Sabrina_cs's answer above will handle the simple case of displaying the data in a pivoted view.  However, you will lose all of the enhanced editing capabilities provided by the various DataGridViewxxxColumn classes.  This can be solved, but you will have to roll your own class to get there.

I have built a class in the past to solve this issue in a generalized fashion.  I can't share the code, as I did it for work, but I can describe the solution for you.

First is a xml-based config file to define the set of rows which will map to the properties.  In our case this config file included order, property names, datatypes, lookup references, presentation (check box, combo box, etc.), header text, read-only status and anything else you think you might want.

At form initialization, you will use this config file to generate the rows in your grid and bind the definition to the row for your code to refer to later.

As you load your data, you will need to do you own binding of values to cells as the built-in binding will not work for you.  If you implement special controls for data beyond just text, you will need to manually bind the correct control to the cell either while initializing the rows or while you bind the actual data.  We used this for boolean -> checkbox and lookup -> combobox.

While data is edited, you will be responsible for updating your own underlying data objects, which you will probably want to associate to the columns while you are loading the data.  You can use reflection to update the property based on the information in the config file.

I know this is not a lot of detail, but hopefully this will provide enough background that you can get an idea about how you can proceed, or if it will be worth the effort.  Depending on how rich an experience you are trying to provide, this could easily be 1000+ lines of code, so it's non-trivial.

For the data-set we were trying to process, our users found this presentation to be an immensely valuable improvement.  YMMV.  Good luck.